# Setting a String to LocalDate converter in Vaadin Table

Tags: java, date, java-8, converters, vaadin

Following the book "Learning Vaadin 7, Second Edition", I am now trying to display simple beans in a table. However, the book only covers the usage of the old java.util.Date class. I am trying to display a LocalDate property with the use of a Converter.

The bean (Person) I am trying to display:

```
public class Person {

private long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private LocalDate birthdate;
private Gender gender;

// .. GETTERS & SETTERS
```

I have written a LocalDateToStringConverter, implementing the com.vaadin.data.util.converter.Converter.

```
package be.kapture.converters;

import com.vaadin.data.util.converter.Converter;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import java.util.Locale;

public class LocalDateToStringConverter implements Converter<String, LocalDate> {

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToModel(String value, Class<? extends LocalDate> targetType, Locale locale) throws ConversionException {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
        try {
            return LocalDate.parse(value, formatter);

        } catch (DateTimeParseException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToPresentation(LocalDate value, Class<? extends String> targetType, Locale locale) throws ConversionException {
        return value.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<LocalDate> getModelType() {
        return LocalDate.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<String> getPresentationType() {
        return String.class;
    }
}
```

In the UI, here's the code snippet where I set the converter:

```
...
Table table = new Table("", container);
table.setConverter("birthdate", new LocalDateToStringConverter());

verticalLayout.addComponent(table);
```

'container' being a BeanItemContainer, in which I put some example Person objects.
When visiting the Vaadin application in my browser I get the following Exception:

```
jun 27, 2016 1:56:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [HelloVaadinServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: com.vaadin.ui.Table$CacheUpdateException: Error during Table cache update. Additional causes not shown.] with root cause
com.vaadin.data.util.converter.Converter$ConversionException: Unable to convert value of type java.time.LocalDate to presentation type class java.lang.String. No converter is set and the types are not compatible.
    at com.vaadin.data.util.converter.ConverterUtil.convertFromModel(ConverterUtil.java:116)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.convertFromModel(AbstractField.java:736)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.convertFromModel(AbstractField.java:721)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.setPropertyDataSource(AbstractField.java:657)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.bindPropertyToField(Table.java:4140)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.getPropertyValue(Table.java:4109)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.parseItemIdToCells(Table.java:2386)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.getVisibleCellsNoCache(Table.java:2225)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.refreshRenderedCells(Table.java:1745)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.refreshRowCache(Table.java:2691)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.containerItemSetChange(Table.java:4587)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.AbstractContainer.fireItemSetChange(AbstractContainer.java:242)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.AbstractInMemoryContainer.fireItemsAdded(AbstractInMemoryContainer.java:1012)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.AbstractInMemoryContainer.fireItemAdded(AbstractInMemoryContainer.java:994)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.AbstractInMemoryContainer.internalAddItemAtEnd(AbstractInMemoryContainer.java:884)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.AbstractBeanContainer.addItem(AbstractBeanContainer.java:533)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.AbstractBeanContainer.addBean(AbstractBeanContainer.java:598)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.BeanItemContainer.addItem(BeanItemContainer.java:227)
    at be.kapture.MyUI.init(MyUI.java:88)
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:682)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:214)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:74)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1409)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:364)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2508)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2497)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Why is it not registering the Converter to do the String to LocalDate conversions (and vice-versa if needed at some point)? I have tried using an anonymous inner class as a parameter in the Table.setConverter method, with the same result. What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE (on request):**

Here is the full UI code where the Table, Container and Converter are being used. Note: it is a "HelloVaadin" sandbox project with no actual goal. It is set-up especially for purposes like this issue, trying to integrate Java 8's LocalDate into Vaadin projects.

```
package be.kapture;

import be.kapture.converters.LocalDateToDateConverter;
import be.kapture.converters.LocalDateToStringConverter;
import be.kapture.entities.Person;
import be.kapture.util.CustomFieldGroupFieldFactory;
import com.vaadin.annotations.*;
import com.vaadin.data.fieldgroup.FieldGroup;
import com.vaadin.data.util.BeanItem;
import com.vaadin.data.util.BeanItemContainer;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.*;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Arrays;

import static com.vaadin.data.Property.ValueChangeListener;


@Theme("mytheme")
@Widgetset("be.kapture.MyAppWidgetset")
@PreserveOnRefresh
@Title("Hello Vaadin!")

public class MyUI extends UI implements Window.CloseListener {

    private static final Person person1 = new Person(1L, "John", "DOE", LocalDate.of(70, 1, 1));
    private static final Person person2 = new Person(2L, "Jane", "doe", LocalDate.of(70, 1, 1));
    private static final Person person3 = new Person(3L, "jules", "winnf", LocalDate.of(48, 11, 21));
    private static final Person person4 = new Person(4L, "vincent", "Vega", LocalDate.of(54, 2, 17));

    private static final BeanItemContainer<Person> container = new BeanItemContainer<>(Person.class);

    static {
        container.addAll(Arrays.asList(person1, person2, person3, person4));
    }

    private final VerticalLayout verticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {

        Person person = new Person(1L);
        person.setFirstName("John");
        person.setLastName("Doe");
        person.setBirthdate(LocalDate.now());

        BeanItem<Person> beanItem = new BeanItem<>(person);

        FieldGroup group = new FieldGroup(beanItem);
        group.setFieldFactory(new CustomFieldGroupFieldFactory());

        Field<?> id = group.buildAndBind("id");
        Field<?> firstName = group.buildAndBind("firstName");
        Field<?> lastName = group.buildAndBind("lastName");

        Field<?> birthdate = group.buildAndBind("birthdate");

        Field<?> gender = group.buildAndBind("gender");

//        birthdate.setConverter(new LocalDateToDateConverter());
//        birthdate.setPropertyDataSource(item.getItemProperty("birthdate"));
//        FormLayout layout = new FormLayout(id, firstName, lastName,
//                birthdate);
//        layout.setMargin(true);
//        setContent(layout);

        verticalLayout.setMargin(true);
        verticalLayout.setSpacing(true);

        verticalLayout.addComponents(id, firstName, lastName, birthdate, gender);

         // Define a person which cannot exist
        Person nullPerson = new Person(-1L);
        nullPerson.setFirstName("Test");
        container.addItem(nullPerson);
        final ListSelect select = new ListSelect("", container);

        // Send events on directly when clicked
        select.setImmediate(true);

        // Handle the value of the person as null
        select.setNullSelectionItemId(nullPerson);
        select.setItemCaptionPropertyId("firstName");
        select.addValueChangeListener((ValueChangeListener) event -> System.out.println(select.getValue()));

        verticalLayout.addComponent(select);

        Table table = new Table("");
        table.setEditable(true);
        table.setConverter(LocalDateToDateConverter.class);
        table.setContainerDataSource(container);

        verticalLayout.addComponent(table);

        setContent( verticalLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClose(Window.CloseEvent e) {
        Notification.show("Window closed.");
    }

    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set the converter before setting the container?

Comment: @A.Meier, the container is set in the constructor parameter of the table. I think I see the error now. The converter should be set first, and then the datasource?

Comment: That's true. The datasource must be set after the converter.

Comment: If that solved the issue, post it as answer please.

Comment: Issue not yet solved. I updated my code to the following:
        Table table = new Table("");
        table.setEditable(true);
        table.setConverter("birthdate", new LocalDateToStringConverter());
        table.setContainerDataSource(container);
This throws the next exception:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PropertyId birthdate must be in the container
Using Table.setConverter(LocalDateToStringConverter.class) gives me the same exception described in the question.

Comment: Can you add the whole code where you add items to container/table? The stack trace implies the exception is raising when an item is added to the BeanItemContainer. When it is added? Are you sure that, at this point, the converter is registered?

Comment: Appended an update in the original question with the code of the UI using the Container, Table and Converter.

Basically, you can ignore most of the Components being used. I'm using a private static final BeanItemContainer<Person>, called 'container', which is initalized in a static block. Later, that container is then used as a datasource for the table.

Comment: table.setConverter(LocalDateToDateConverter.class) sets a converter for the value of the table. You want to set a converter for showing "birthdate" so you should use table.setConverter("birthdate",LocalDateToDateConverter.class);

Comment: @ArturSignell > This was covered in my updated question. The container/datasource should be set AFTER the converter is set. So calling the setConverter method with the propertyID parameter "birthdate" will throw an exception, telling us that the field "birthdate" could not be found when setting the converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was curious and figured out your problem. The method [`setConverter(Object, Converter)`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Table.html#setConverter(java.lang.Object,%20com.vaadin.data.util.converter.Converter)) just allows to change how values in that column are displayed to the user (textual representation). That's why the second argument's type is `Converter<java.lang.String,?>`.

In your example you enabled editing in table. This requires Vaadin to know how it will provide a table cell editor for your `LocalDate` column. By default, the table doesn't know about `LocalDate`. I am aware of 2 options you have:

1. Implement a [converter factory](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Changing+the+default+converters+for+an+application) that returns a `Converter` for `LocalDate` to `String`. The table component is then able to show a text field where you can enter a date according to the format in your converter. I did not try what happened when user enters an invalid string.
2. Implement a [table field factory](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-table.html#components.table.editing.fieldfactories) and call [setTableFieldFactory](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Table.html#setTableFieldFactory(com.vaadin.ui.TableFieldFactory)) on table component. The field factory would display a `PopupDateField` or something similar. This way you are type-safe and can use built-in date fields.

IMO the latter would be a better user experience but of course it is more effort in development.

Comment: I believe your answer is spot on, sir Harbich. After commenting out the setEditable call, the UI is generated without errors. The LocalDate fields are shown in the table in a simple TextField. 

A TableFieldFactory seems not to be so easy as first thought. I suppose one would need a converter from LocalDate to Date to be able to show it in a PopupDateField? I don't see how Vaadin could display a non-recognised date type in its out-of-the-box components otherwise.

Comment: That's right, you need to implement a converter from LocalDate (model) to Date (presentation) and set that converter to the PopupDateField which could be done in the TableFieldFactory.

Comment: I've gotten the code to work, with editable fields now thanks to your input Steffen!  
As reference for future readers: implement a TableFieldFactory and a Converter<Date, LocalDate>. In the overridden createField method in your factory:  
check if (LocalDate.class.isAssignableFrom(property.getType()))  
create new PopupDateField (or whatever you want), on the Field/Component call setConverter method with your converter, call setPropertyDatasource with the right datasource, and return it! For all other types, delegate creation to DefaultFieldFactory.get().createField.

Comment: I'm experiencieng the same problem with Grid, but the cannot solve it as I'm unable to find any equivalen to TableFieldFactory for this component. Any hints?